# JAVA DATE : GET Locale based valid date formats stored in the OS

Tags: java, validation, date

IF I go to regional settings in windows 7. there are following valid date formats :

following formats for INDIA :

```
dd-MM-yyyy
dd-MM-yy
d-M-yy
d.M.yy
yyyy-MM-dd
```

formats for USA :

```
yyyy-MM-dd
M/d/yyyy
M/d/yy
MM/dd/yy
MM/dd/yyyy
yy/MM/dd
yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MMM-yy
```

how to get all valid date formats for particular locale from JAVA 8 date api?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
String[] str= {"dd-MM-yyyy", "M/d/yyyy", "M/d/yy","MM/dd/yyyy","M/d/yyyy",
                "yyyy-MM-dd", "yy/MM/dd", "M/d/yyyy"}; 
//Provide all the date formats here

public Date tryParse(String myDate)
{
    for (String s: str)
    {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(s).parse(myDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: No Hardcoding at all. If I submit en_US as locale, code should dynamically find out valid formats for date in USA as I listed in Question.

Comment: @javafan:- Have you checked the [DateTime Formatter class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: YES. that technique gets me one locale specific format.  I need all the possible valid formats based on locale, I am in USA, so en_US is the locale, if one goes to regional settings in Windows, there are following valid formats:   yyyy-MM-dd
M/d/yyyy
M/d/yy
MM/dd/yy
MM/dd/yyyy
yy/MM/dd
yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MMM-yy